# Filtros ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Saludos tengo una vista en ASP MVC donde muestra una tabla y tiene 3 dropdownlist que sirven como filtro.

En el controlador retornara lo que se escoja en los dropdwonlist los operadores logico `&&` sirven para que a la hora de mostrar los datos sea obligatorio utilizar los 3 filtros:

```
  var incidencias = db.vwVisitadorComisiones
            .Where(x =>

            x.Mes == buscarMes
            && x.Equipo == buscarEquipos
            && x.Region == buscarRegiones

              ).ToList();
```

Y aqui esta la parte de los filtros en la vista:

```
    <div class="m-5">
    <div class="card" id="carta">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                Mes: @Html.DropDownList("buscarMes", "all")
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Equipo: @Html.DropDownList("buscarEquipos", "all")
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Regiones: @Html.DropDownList("buscarRegiones", "all")
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Buscar" />
            <button id='btnExport' class="btn btn-success">Exportar</button>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pues necesito hacer que la pagina retorne los datos con solo utilizar un filtro es decir que si selecciono un mes me traiga todos los equipos y regiones.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con parámetros opcionales al momento de realizar el WHERE, de la siguiente manera

```
...Where(x => (x.campo == value.campo || value.campo == null))
```

De esta manera al incluir la condición *OR igual NULL*, estas devolviendo todo o si tu `Dropdown` viene con algún dato, realiza el filtro en base a ese valor

Debería quedar algo como esto

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get(SearchViewModel value)
{
   IEnumerable<Usuarios> list = Entity.Where(x => (x.campo1 == value.campo1 || value.campo1 == null) && (x.campo2 == value.campo2 || value.campo2 == null) && (x.campo3 == value.campo3 || value.campo3 == null) && x.campoObligatorio == value.campoObligatorio);
   return list;
}
```

Nos comentas si te sirve :D